# Error in Google SDTT: "A value for the valueName field is required"

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

I’m implementing Schema.org + JSON-LD for my site and trying to add the following in all pages of the site:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebSite",
    "url": "http://example.com/",
    "potentialAction": {
      "@type": "SearchAction",
      "target": "http://example.com/search?&q={query}",
      "query-input": "required",
      "valueName":""
    }
}
</script>
```

I tried to provide multiple values for `valueName`, but still Google Structured Data Testing Tool reports this as an error.

[image: Google SDTT output shows error 'A value for the valueName field is required']

What is a valid value for `valueName`?

Comment: @Rob IMHO this is a valid `schema.org` and `json-ld` question.

Comment: @JayGray The original question was less clear than this twice edited one. I'll remove my flags.

Answer (score 4):

You can either provide a string value for `query-input`, in which case you have to specify the part of the `target` value that represents the placeholder ("query" in your case), prefixed by "required name=" (no space characters):

```json
"target": "http://example.com/search?&q={query}",
"query-input": "required name=query",
```

Or you can provide a `PropertyValueSpecification` item value for `query-input`, in which case you can use `valueName` and `valueRequired` explicitly:

```json
"target": "http://example.com/search?&q={query}",
"query-input": {
  "@type": "PropertyValueSpecification",
  "valueName": "query",
  "valueRequired": true
}
```

In [Sitelinks Searchbox](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitelinks-searchbox), Google only documents the first way. The second way is what their [testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) parses when using the first way.